# Proportion of numbers with prime divisors from restricted set

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let $X$ be large, and let $\mathcal{P} \subset \{1, \dots, X\}$ be a set of primes. What is a good upper bound for
$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq n \leq X,\\ p \nmid n \text{ for all }p \in \mathcal{P}}} 1.
$$
From standard arguments in sieve theory (Brun's sieve, I think) one obtains that the sum in question is
$$
\ll X \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p} \right).
$$
However, if $\mathcal{P}$ is close to maximal (close to containing all primes in the range $\{1, \dots, X\}$), then this estimate seems to be far from being optimal. For example, when $\mathcal{P}$ contains *all* the primes in this range, then the sum equals 1, since not other number in $\{1, \dots, X\}$ is coprime to all primes in this range, while the upper bound above is around $X/\log X$.

That was a trivial example of course, but what happens when $\mathcal{P}$ contains "most" primes in the given range? Assume, for example, that $\mathcal{P}$ is so large that $\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} p^{-1} \geq (1-\varepsilon) \log \log X$, for fixed $\varepsilon$. Then what is a good upper bound for the sum above? (As noted, here $\varepsilon$ is fixed and "small", and $X \to \infty$.)

Comment: Disclaimer : I know nothing about sieve theory and the following proposition may be utterly stupid, but as a former expected-to-become physicist, I would try to investigate an upper bound of the form  $X/(\log^{1-\delta}X.X^{\delta} )$ with  $ \delta\sim\pi_{\mathcal{P}}(x)/\pi(x) $ where  $ \pi_{\mathcal{P}}(x) $ is the number of elements of  $ \mathcal{P} $ .

Answer (score 9):

This question is addressed by [Granville, Koukoulopoulos, and Matomaki](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0413) (paper in Duke) and its sequel by [Matomaki and Shao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02371).  These results show that for the sieve bound is of the right size, then ${\mathcal P}$ should omit a good number of large primes.   In other words the situation where one does much better than the sieve bound is when all the large primes are in ${\mathcal P}$ -- think of the situation of smooth numbers.  Conditions like $\sum_{p\in {\mathcal P}} 1/p \ge (1-\epsilon)\log \log X$ are too coarse in this problem.